# check Gorenstein ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, formal-power-series, gorenstein

I have a problem saying

"Check that $k[[x,y,z]]/(x^3-z^2,y^2-xz,z^3)$ is a Gorenstein ring while $k[[x,y,z]]/(x,y,z)^2$ is not, given $k$ is a field."

Anyway, easily check that Krull dimensions of both rings are 0. And there is a theorem stating "$R$ is Gorenstein iff $l_R(0:m)=1$ given that $(R,m)$ is Noetherian local ring".

I used this theorem and since $$(x,y,z)/(x,y,z)^2=(0:_{k[[x,y,z]]/(x,y,z)^2} (x,y,z)/(x,y,z)^2) \supset (x,y^2,z^2,xy,xz,yz)/(x,y,z)^2 \supset
(x,y,z)^2/(x,y,z)^2,$$ the latter is not Gorenstein.

But I cannot use the same technique to prove the former, since unlike the latter, I cannot find $(0:m)$.

So, can anyone help me solve this? Did I choose the right approach?

Comment: I find easier to see that it is a complete intersection.

Comment: Anyway, $(0:m)=(x^2yz^2)$.

Comment: Can you tell me how you find it? And how can I prove it?

Comment: You are definitely right, if we can prove your assertion, we claim what we need. But can you givw more details?

Comment: I easily guessed $x^2yz^2$ and I've checked this with Macaulay2.

Comment: that is great. But do you have any suggestions to approach a problem like this by hand? So you guess $x^2 y z^2$, all we need to prove is $((x^3-z^2,y^2-xz,z^3):(x,y,z))\subset (x^2 y z^2)$, I take $f$ in the former and how do I continue?